# Is there a way to programmatically tell when Project has finished Publishing to Project Server?

Tags: ms-project, csom, project-server, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2016

I have a tool that is going to open a MS Project file off the Project Web App (PWA/Project Server). and make some changes. I then need to save the file and [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Project.Application.Publish) the changes before closing it and checking it it. Project Server has issues when a file is checked in before the publish process is complete. I'm trying to find something in the API that will indicate when the publish is complete but I can't find anything.

Is there any way I can programmatically tell when the publish to Project Server is complete?

I've attempted to call the `Application.Publish` method before the `Application.FileCloseEx(PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave, CheckIn: true)` method but the `FileCloseEx` method will execute before the publish is complete in my tests

Maybe something in the CSOM library can access the Project Server's queued jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this by using the [CSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/getting-started-with-the-project-server-csom-and-net) NuGet package:

```
// add this using statement at the top of the file.
using PWA = Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client; 


public static PWA.JobState WaitForProjectToFinishPublishing(string projectName, string serverUrl)
    {
        PWA.JobState jState = PWA.JobState.Failed;
        
        PWA.ProjectContext serverContext = null;

        using (serverContext = new PWA.ProjectContext(serverUrl))
        {
            try
            {
                serverContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                // Query PWA for the Projects
                serverContext.Load(serverContext.Projects);
                serverContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // get the project we are wanting to wait to finish publishing
                var pubPrj = serverContext.Projects.Where(p => p.Name == projectName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (pubPrj != null)
                {
                    // Query PWA for the Queued jobs of the Project. (Publish will be one of the queued jobs if it is still publishing)
                    serverContext.Load(pubPrj.QueueJobs);
                    serverContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // get the publish job
                    var publishJob = pubPrj.QueueJobs.Where(qJ => qJ.MessageType == PWA.QueueMsgType.ProjectPublish).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (publishJob != null)
                    {
                        // use the WaitForQueue method to wait for the publish job to finish. Timeout after 5 minutes (large projects can take some time to publish)
                        jState = serverContext.WaitForQueue(publishJob, 300);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log something if you want
            }
        }

        return jState;
    }
```